# how to do sed in-line replacement without backup file if the original file is not changed ? in case the file was not changed

Tags: sed

I would like to retain a backup file, only if sed altered the original file.

for example: 
I have the following file:

```
# cat test
This is example file
abcd
efgh
```

process with sed so there is nothing to change:

```
# sed -i.BAK "s/AAAA/BBBB/" test
```

The "test" file is not changed because nothing matched. In this case, I would like to **avoid** the backup file that was created:

```
# md5sum test*
d3ca57583595576338ad6f9a01276cd5  test
d3ca57583595576338ad6f9a01276cd5  test.BAK
```

Comment: `sed ... && if cmp -s test test.BAK; then rm test.BAK; fi`? So just remove the bak file is nothing changed.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk. But I'm wondering if there is a clean way to **prevent** sed of creating the backup file.

Comment: "clean" is not an objective term. Please describe precisely what you really want. Reading the manual, I find no `sed` built-in way to do it, but you can surely find another way of achieving the same result (as the one KamilCuk described). Would that be acceptable?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like a solution where a backup file will be created if the modified file is different from the original, but otherwise the backup file would **never** be created to begin with (rather than creating it regardless and then removing it if not needed). If that is your question, then the answer is "nope, can't do". There are two good reasons for that. One is that `sed` is a **stream** editor. It edits a line, then it moves on to the next; in particular, it can't look ahead. Suppose there were no changes on the first line. (continued)

Comment: Do you create the backup file at this point? If there will be no changes on any of the remaining lines, the answer should be "no" - but if there will be changes later, then the answer should be "yes". You don't know the answer at this point, though. And if on line 100 you finally do have a change, line 1 is long gone. (Basically that's what "stream" means.) This kind of "stream" processing is why `sed`, and similar utilities, can keep a small memory footprint, regardless of how big the input stream is. (continued)

Comment: A second reason - which will also affect full-file utilities like `vi`, not just `sed` - is that real changes may still result in the output file being identical to the original. Suppose for example that the change is to remove the first character from every line and add an `x` at the end of the line. If every line is all-x strings, like `xxxx` and `xxxxxxx`, then the output is identical to the input even though every line matches, and there are actual changes on every line - even though the output is the same as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that what I was asking is not possible by "sed" as I suspected by RTFM.

I solved by adding "if [ grep ... ] " on the expression needed to replace. 
The "sed" is performed  if and only if the expression exists.

Thanks for the people that commented.